# $n$-dimensional integral on a ball

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate the following integral and get an expression depending on the dimension $n$ for some positive constants $a$, $b$ and $c$
$$
\int_{B}(c-a|x|^2)^b   \,dx
$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and where $B$ is the $n$-ball centered at $0$ with radius $\sqrt{c/a}$.
Note that $|x|^2=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: use a change of variable $x = r \omega$ with $\omega \in S^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you eventually get$$
\frac{c^b}{d}\left(\frac{c\pi}{a}\right)^\frac{d}{2}\frac{\Gamma(1+b)}{\Gamma\left(1+b+\frac{d}{2}\right)}.
$$

Comment: what does "eventually" mean?

Answer (score 1):

We may assume $a=c=1$; hence $B\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ is the unit ball. Writing $$x=r\>\omega \qquad(0\leq r\leq1, \ \omega\in S^{n-1})$$
we get 
$${\rm d}(x)=r^{n-1}{\rm d}\omega\>dr\ ,$$
whereby ${\rm d}\omega$ denotes the $(n-1)$-dimensional euclidean surface element on $S^{n-1}$. It follows that
$$\int_B(1-|x|^2)^b\>{\rm d}(x)=\omega(S^{n-1})\int_0^1 (1-r^2)^b\>r^{n-1}\>dr\ .$$

Comment: What is $\omega(S^{n-1})$, the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Comment: It is the surface of the [n-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), $\frac{2 \pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$

Comment: Sorry, $n-1$-sphere!